# know the number of columns from text file, separated by space or tab

Tags: c++, text-files, multiple-columns

I need to know the number of columns from a text file with floats.

I've made like this to know the number of lines:

```
inFile.open(pathV); 

// checks if file opened
if(inFile.fail()) {
    cout << "error loading .txt file for reading" << endl; 
    return;
}
// Count the number of lines
int NUMlines = 0;
while(inFile.peek() != EOF){
    getline(inFile, dummyLine);
    NUMlines++;
}
inFile.close();
cout << NUMlines-3 << endl; // The file has 3 lines at the beginning that I don't read
```

A line of the .txt :

```
189.53  58.867  74.254  72.931  80.354
```

The number of values can vary from file to file but not on the same file.

Each value have a variable number of decimal places after the "." (dot)

The values can be separated by a space or a TAB.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Given a line you have read, called `line` this works:

```
std::string line("189.53  58.867  74.254  72.931  80.354");
std::istringstream iss(line);
int columns = 0;
do
{
    std::string sub;
    iss >> sub;
    if (sub.length())
        ++columns;
}
while(iss);
```

I don't like that this reads the whole line, and then reparses it, but it works.

There are various other ways of splitting strings e.g. boost's  `<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` See previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can read one line, then [split it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) and count number of elements.

Or you can read one line, then iterate through it as an array and count number of *space* and `\t` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily if these three assumptions are true:

1. `dummyLine` is defined so that you have access to it outside the `while` loop scope
2. The last line of the file has the same tab/space delimited format (Cause that's what `dummyLine` will contain after the `while` loop)
3. One and only one tab/space occurs between numbers on each line

If all these are true, then right after the `while` loop you'll just need to do this:

```
const int numCollums = std::count( dummyLine.begin(), dummyLine.end(), '\t' ) + std::count( dummyLine.begin(), dummyLine.end(), ' ' ) + 1;
```

Comment: I got an error:
Error: Function count(dummyLine.begin(),dummyLine.end(),'\t') is not defined in current scope
Can you specify count()?

Comment: At the top of the file this code is in `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: I'm using root, and I can't use all the C++ functionalities, and the same error appear...

Comment: When you say you're "using root" you mean that you're `using namespace std;` or do you mean something else? Clearly you have access to std functionality cause you're using a `std::string` and `std::fstream` so as long as you include algorithm you should also have access to `std::count`.

Comment: Don't forget to tip your waitresses, and accept correct answers.